# Display PickerView when touch UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview, swift2

I Word with Xcode 7 and Swift 2
I would like to create a function that displays a PickerView when I click on my UITextView. 
How should I do?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by changing the `inputView` property of your `UITextView` to your `UIPickerView` object.
something like this:

```
myTextView.inputView = myPickerView;
```

Hope this helps!